# Error when using WYGWAM 3.2.1 & Assets 2.2.2 with EE < 2.6

Tags: assets, wygwam

According to the [WYGWAM Installing and Updating](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/installation.html) page, WYGWAM requires ExpressionEngine 2.4 or late.

However, if you are using both WYGWAM 3.2.1 and Assets 2.2.2 (may be the same for older versions) and you are running an EE version less than 2.6, you are likely going to get the following error when attempting to access any of the Editor Configurations within WYGWAM's settings:

> Call to undefined function ee() in
>   /PATH/TO/INSTALL/DIR/system/expressionengine/third_party/wygwam/mcp.wygwam.php
>   on line 139

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty easy to resolve. Simply open up:

/expressionengine/third_party/wygwam/mcp.wygwam.php

and change line 139 from:

```
$all_sources = ee()->assets_lib->get_all_sources();
```

to

```
$all_sources = $this->EE->assets_lib->get_all_sources();
```

Looks like this is the only reference to the ee() global in the codebase. Because this code block exists in a conditional which only gets executed if you are using Assets, you won't run into this problem if you are using the native File Manager.

Comment: I've got Assets 1.2.2 (yeah, I know), and WYGWAM 3.2.2 on EE 2.5.2. This fix doesn't quite work, I think because get_all_sources isn't available in Assets 1.2.2. I don't have a workaround yet.

Comment: ETA: Updating to Assets 2.2.2 works.